# Error in fitting Two-Part Mixed Effects Model for Semi-Continuous Data with GLMMadaptive

Tags: r, mixed-model, repeated-measures, zero-inflation, glmmadaptive

I am having trouble fitting a Two-Part Mixed Effects Model for Semi-Continuous Data to my data using the GLMMadaptive package.
My trail includes: 2 wines, 2 treatments, samples seven times over 100 days, stored a 2 different temperatures, with 3 replicates at each sampling event. The goal is to monitor the formation of a certain molecule in time. The first 2-3 sampling events reported a concentration of 0.001 (=0) while the concentration increased afterwards.
I tried to fit the following model

```
m <- mixed_model(Fosetyl ~ Treat*Temp*Day, random = ~ Treat| W_ID, data = dfws, 
                  family = hurdle.lognormal(), n_phis = 1,
                  zi_fixed = ~ Treat,iter_EM = 0)
```

Unfortunately the model does not run even if with scaled variables. This is the error message:

```
Warning: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge
Error in mixed_fit(y, X, Z, X_zi, Z_zi, id, offset, offset_zi, family,  : 
  A large coefficient value has been detected during the optimization.
 Please re-scale you covariates and/or try setting the control argument
 'iter_EM = 0'. Alternatively, this may due to a
 divergence of the optimization algorithm, indicating that an overly
 complex model is fitted to the data. For example, this could be
 caused when including random-effects terms (e.g., in the
 zero-inflated part) that you do not need. Otherwise, adjust the
 'max_coef_value' control argument.
```

I have read the GLMMadaptive support material but could not find a solution. I have experience in mixed modelling but not on this package. So...

1. Any idea why i get this error?
2. Is two-part mixed effect the correct model to analyze my dataset
3. How should I take into account the temporal correlation (is a repeated measure).

Thank you for any input you can provide

Comment: This warning message seems relatively clear (some R warning messages are much less so). It lists several possibilities, including that the model may be too complex. You have all the interactions of treatment, temperature, and day. That's a lot, because day has 100 levels. You are asking for estimates of a huge number of things.

Comment: @PeterFlom thank you for your reply. I thought about that but actually I receive the same message if I include only Treatment in the fixed effect and (1|W_ID) as random effect. So it must be something else...

Comment: Have you tried setting the `max_coef_value` to a larger number, e.g., 50?

Comment: @DimitrisRizopoulos Thank you for helping. I have tried but i get the following error: ```Warning: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge
Warning in mixed_model(Fosetyl ~ Treat * Day * Temp, random = ~Treat | W_ID,  :
  Hessian matrix at convergence is not positive definite; unstable solution.```

Comment: This indicates that you are fitting a model that is too complex for your data. I would suggest removing the three-way interaction. Also, you probably do not want to include a random slope for `Treat` in the random-effects part.

Comment: Unfortunately, I receive the same error also with a much simpler model like the following. ```m <- mixed_model(Fosetyl ~ Treat, random = ~ 1| W_ID, data = dfws, 
                  family = hurdle.lognormal(), n_phis = 1,
                  zi_fixed = ~ Treat,iter_EM = 0,max_coef_value=50)```

Comment: @DimitrisRizopoulos would you haven any suggestions concerning my last comment? I am a bit stuck. thank you

Comment: Not without trying myself.

Comment: @DimitrisRizopoulos if you wish I could send you a section of the data. Thank you